# Creating array of nested json object using nlohmann json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Assumed I have this struct:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    struct Point
    {
        int x; int y;
    };
    std::string color;
    std::array<Point,4> points;
};
```

and I want to implement `to_json()` method for `Rectangle`.
I know this method must be in the same namespace of the corresponding type.

So if `Point` declared outside of `Rectangle`, like this:

```
struct Point
{
    int x; int y;
};

void to_json(json& j, const Point& p) {

    j = json{ {"x", p.x}, {"y", p.y} };
}

struct Rectangle
{
    std::string color;
    std::array<Point,4> points;
};

void to_json(json& j, const Rectangle& r) {
    
    j = json{ {"color", r.color}, {"points", r.points} };
}
```

this is working, but how can it be implemented when `Point` is a nested type?

Comment: I’d try `void to_json(json& j, const Rectangle::Point& p)` first. Not sure does that work though.

Comment: @numzero seem to work for me. thank you very much.